# How to set up a localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I've been teaching myself the basics of Angularjs, but turns out in order to get the 'routing' working I need to set up a localhost. I've installed XAMPP and ran both Apache and MySql.

However, whenever I run an Angular page on the localhost it throws an error - coming from the angularjs.js itself. What am I missing? And how to get the routing working please? Am I using the wrong localhost?

Comment: Post you error please

Comment: Can you post the error and your code

Comment: This is what the Console shows me (derives it from angular.min.js) : ** ...gify(arguments[c]):arguments[c]);return Error(a)}}function Pa(b){if(null==b||Ga(...

 
**

Comment: **Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAppsRouting&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0AD%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F**

Answer (score 0):

Just put your complete code in apache htdocs folder.

Comment: First check sever is running ..??
Simple localhost:80

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need to set up XAMPP for AngularJS, because AngualarJS is a frontend library for Javascript therefore in compiles in the browser, so there's no need to set up a local server using Apache/XAMPP. Instead, run your site using a text editor like [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). Remember, the only instance where you need to use XAMPP is if you are running a serverside language like PHP, Perl, Python, ext.